# application crash in release mode due to some ORMLite issue

Tags: android, ormlite

I am getting error when application runs in a release mode.

here is the error.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.crazyhitty.chdev.ks.firebasechat, PID: 20397
>                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'uid' in table k
>                                                          at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableInfo.getFieldTypeByColumnName(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.findColumnFieldType(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.eq(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.crazyhitty.chdev.ks.firebasechat.d.f.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.crazyhitty.chdev.ks.firebasechat.ui.activities.PhoneAuthActivity.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.crazyhitty.chdev.ks.firebasechat.ui.activities.PhoneAuthActivity$5.onComplete(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

As mentioned in error, **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'uid' in table k** But, I am not having any table k instead my table name is user

Here is my proguard file

```
 -dontnote com.facebook.Session
 -dontnote com.facebook.FacebookSdk
 -keepnames class com.facebook.Session {}
 -keepnames class com.facebook.FacebookSdk {}


  -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil

  -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
  -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

  -keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
  -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**


  -dontwarn okio.**
  -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**
  -keep interface com.squareup.okhttp3.* { *; }
  -dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
  -dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault

  -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
  -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

 -keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
  protected Object[][] getContents();
  }

 -keep public class   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
  public static final *** NULL;
}

 -keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
 -keepclassmembernames class * {
   @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
  }

  -keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;

   }

  -keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
  -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
  -keep class com.google.common.collect.** { *; }

  -keep @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip class *
  -keepclassmembers class * {
     @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip *;
   }


   -keepclassmembers class * {
      native <methods>;
   }


 -dontwarn okio.**
 -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
 -dontwarn okhttp3.**
 -dontwarn javax.annotation.**
 -dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**
 -dontwarn com.facebook.infer.**

 -keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
 -keep public enum   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
**[] $VALUES;
public *;
}

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
-dontwarn javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy


-dontwarn com.android.installreferrer.api.**
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.appindexing.**
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

-keep class org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException{*;}

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
 @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
 }
 -keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }


-keepclassmembers class * extends    org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
 <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

application works fine in debug mode. but for release mode I am getting crash because of above error. Can any one please help me?

Comment: add this line in proGuard `-keepattributes Signature` and `-keep class <our.package.name>.db.** { *; }`

Comment: @MohammedFarhan that didn't help :(

Comment: when ormlite is about to create a dao table it looks for annotations `@DatabaseField` for every field in POJO class. Maybe your ProGuard is failing to find/ or removing annotations. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753051/obfuscating-ormlite-model-classes-with-proguard)

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'uid' in table k at
> ```

You say you don't have any table `k` but that's how ORMLite is seeing your class.  Proguard's job is to obfuscate the code and it must be changing your `User` class to `k`.

You need to make sure that proguard is not changing your `User` class.  You should add something like:

```
-keep class com.example.db.Entities.** { *; }
```

Obviously you should change the package to match your database entities.  See this answer: [Proguard with OrmLite on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853096/proguard-with-ormlite-on-android/41119516#41119516)